# How do I set multifactor authentication on windows azure management?

Tags: security, azure

Simple, straightforward, but not obvious at all... I set up a management account tied to a Microsoft ID. I use my MSID to log into the Azure management console, and now I'd like to add two-factor just to the management console but for the life of me, I cannot find how/where to do so. It's got to be obvious, but I'm still quite new to Azure.

The articles I've found are about integrating MFA with Azure services - that's a next step at some point, but for now I just want to apply the additional security layer to my management console.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't enable Azure MFA for Microsoft Account sourced Azure users, but you can enable it for the Microsoft Account. Go to https://account.live.com then 'Manage Advanced Security' then enable and turn on 'Two-step verification'. The next time you log into Azure using the Microsoft ID you'll be asked for the verification number.